# How can I prevent Google Cloud Functions to generate small offsets when subtracting a number?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've got some really strange behavior with subtracting numbers in Google Firestore with Google Cloud Functions.

Here is my test Google Functions code:

```
exports.testCounter = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    db.collection('counter').doc('test').update({
        count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-0.0005)
    });
});
```

And then I call the function from the cli:

```
firebase functions:shell
testCounter({test: "demo"})
```

This is the document I created to test:
[Initial Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ4lb.png)

Then after the first execution everything works exactly as expected and the number 5 is now 4.9995.:
[Document after first execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iumws.png)

However after the second execution 4.9995 is not 4.9990 as expected, but it changes to 4.9990000000000006.:
[Document after second execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x93Jv.png)

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Or is this somehow expected behavior?

Thanks and have a great day!

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard behavior for floating point numbers using the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard, which is what [Firestore uses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).  Put briefly, computers lose precision when storing floating point data efficiently.

If you aren't able to accept this behavior, you should not store floating point numbers at all, and instead just store integers.  The integer should contain all of the required precision that you would normally need for the floating point equivalent, except you mulitiply the float by the required precision.

For example, if you need three decimal points of precision (e.g. 5.005), multiply that float by 1000, drop the fractional part, and store the integer 5005.  If you need to add .005, then you should instead add 5.  Then you can format that number any way you want on the client.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a Firebase problem, just inherent to floating point numbers.

```
(4.9990000006).toFixed(4); // 4.9990
```

Replace the parameter `4` in `toFixed` with whatever precision you need.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Doug, the problem comes from the floating point numbers behaviour.

One solution is to use, in your Cloud Function, the [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/) library.

It works well in Cloud Functions (as in any Node.js code), but it  means that you will not be able to use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment()` anymore.